# How to point to jdk1.8 in eclipse juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, ubuntu-14.04

I want to use Glassfish 4.1 as server. The problem is I can't add it in eclipse juno.

I go to Window -> Preferences -> Servers -> Runtime Environments.

I click "Add...", choose Glassfish 4.0 from the menu, click "Next". The following image explains what my problem is...

[image]

The problem is that I can't install server adapter.
As you can see, it says: "This server runtime requires JRE 1.7 or higher", and if I change to
jre8 or default jre, it says that it requires full JDK instead of jre.

NOTE: I have added "jdk1.8.0.20" from "Installed JRE preferences".

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

P.S.: I am not 100% sure that I installed java correctly, but when i type `java -version` this is what I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

and
    `$javac -version` produces `javac 1.8.0_20`

$JAVA_HOME is set to /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin, and this is also added to $PATH

Please tell me how to solove this, and also if I got java installed properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse Juno does not have Java 8 support AFAIK. You need to install JDK7.

Comment: So what's your suggestion? Because I have tried Eclipse Luna, and there I have problem adding glassfish server adapter. It is not even available for download, so I cannot use glassfish at all.

Comment: Just add JDK 7 to your Eclipse installation. Don't use JDK 8.

Comment: Use Eclipse Marketplace to install GlassFish Tools into Eclipse Luna.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik: Tnx, that worked.